# SyntaxError: illlegal return statement [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, syntax-error, bots

The following line throws the error:

```
if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;
```

I'm following this tutorial= [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNouIznypvM&list=PLdnyVeMcpY7_IiC977keSLBXXJG_I3vUo)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json")
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
    
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
for (const file of commandFiles) {
   const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
   client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
    
client.on('message', message => {
      if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
     const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
      const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
      if (message.content === `${prefix}serverinfo`) {
        message.channel.send(message.guild.name)
        message.channel.send(`Total Members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`)
      } else if (message.content === `${prefix}me`) {
        message.channel.send(`Username: ${message.author.username}`)
        message.channel.send(`ID: ${message.author.id}`)
      } else if (message.content === `${prefix}boi`) {
        message.channel.send('BOI')
      }
});
    
if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;
```

Comment: Please edit this post to make the question clearer.

Comment: `return` is used in functions, the line is outside of a function

Answer (score 1):

You can't `return` in the top scope, `return` must be inside a function.

You may either put the logic inside an `if` statement

```js
if (client.commands.has(command)) {
  const command = client.commands.get(command);
  try {
    command.execute(message, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply("There was an issue executing that command!")
  }
  client.login(token);
}
```

Or wrap the logic inside a function, an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) may be a good choice:

```js
(() => {
  if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(command);
  try {
    command.execute(message, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply("There was an issue executing that command!")
  }
  client.login(token);
})();
```